# How to calculate R^2 from n, all possible subset regression models, and SSEs given for those models.

Tags: statistics

[Only the first two columns and n=13 were given.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVv0L.png)

So n=13 is given, and the first two columns of the image attached are also given. Finding the ps was easy, just the number of regressors in the first column+1, finding MSEs was also easy, divide the SSEs by (n-p). Now I'm completely stuck. How am I supposed to find the R^2 values (adjusted or otherwise) without the SSTs? (or SSRs which I can add the SSEs to).

I'm also getting incorrect values for the (adjusted) **Cp** using the formulas:

Cp = SSE/MSE + 2p - n

**Cp**= Cp - 2(n-p)/(n-r-2)

I'd really appreciated some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example for the $R^2$ in the second row from the $SS_E$ numbers:

$$1- \frac{1265.69}{2715.76} \approx 0.5339$$

and the other $R^2$ are calculated similarly

Comment: Didn't realize the SST is the same across all models (and as such the model with no regressors has an SSE=SST). Thanks a lot!